# Increasing recognition tolerance for nft markers with ar.js? Glitching accepted

Tags: image, augmented-reality, aframe, tracking, ar.js

I'm working on a project where we track images in public spaces.

Currently we use ar.js with aframe to track nft markers and to show gltf models with animation.

//That's super great because people with few knowledge can start messing around and still get results. Thanks for that!

It is difficult to match the tracked images outside. (light, wheater etc...)

**Is there a possibility to increase the tolerance? I'd rather have my models shown more than less. In my case a wrongly shown model is better than no model.**

**Thanks in advance and greetings!**

https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js

Comment: About [artoolkitX Natural Feature Tracker (NFT)](https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkitx/wiki/Creating-and-using-NFT-markers)

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation of NFT-marker:
https://github.com/Carnaux/NFT-Marker-Creator

here is settings you could try when creating nft-marker:

```
-level=n
     (n is an integer in range 0 (few) to 4 (many). Default 2.'
-sd_thresh=<sd_thresh>
-max_thresh=<max_thresh>
-min_thresh=<min_thresh>
-leveli=n
     (n is an integer in range 0 (few) to 3 (many). Default 1.'
-feature_density=<feature_density>
-dpi=f: 
      Override embedded JPEG DPI value.
-max_dpi=<max_dpi>
-min_dpi=<min_dpi>
```

P.S. I also currently do not recommend ar.js for image tracking, it works terrible. try another libs

Comment: Which libs would you recommend?  I don't need the actual AR, just the image tracking.

Answer (score -2):

You can set your preferences as [described in the docs](https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/image-tracking/).

Comment: This means no..? I thought smoothing referred to the animation once tracking is activated.
I could not find any positive impact by adjusting smoothing.

Comment: @Uranol did you solve this? I would like somehow "throttle" the recognition/not-recognition; because at the moment there is a lot of flickering - I would like somehow overjump some of the "marker-lost" events. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: There is nothing like NFT-marker documentation on your link )) Smoothing and etc is exactly NOT what have been asked in question!